# All I want is to access a H2 mem database in Websphere V8 using JPA 2.0

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, websphere, persistence.xml

I've been struggling with this for days now and I searched dozens of articles in StackOverflow and other dev sites.

I used the Deployment Manager interface to configure a Websphere Application Server 8.0.0.3 with a H2 JDBC provider and a Data Source for my application using a tutorial I've found [here](http://wiki.ivonet.nl/display/howto/Creating+a+H2+DataSource+using+WebSphere+Application+Server).

JDBC Data Source:

```
Name: H2 JDBC Provider
Classpath: $(H2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH)/h2-1.3.161.jar
Implementation class name: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
```

Data Source:

```
Provider: H2 JDBC Provider
Name: SGO_datasource
JNDI name: jdbc/sgodb
Use this data source in container managed persistence (CMP): true
Data store helper class name: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.ConnectJDBCDataStoreHelper (user-defined)
(default values for all the rest)
Custom properties:
    URL: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    user: sa
    password: sa
```

I tested this datasource using the Test connection button in the DM and it worked fine.

When I try to access this datasource from my app I get this error on first access:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1227818 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property.
```

After reading this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718775/org-apache-openjpa-persistence-argumentexception-while-running-the-main-class), I checked the location of my persistence.xml file in the WAR generated and it seems to be in the right location: WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml.

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="sgo">
      <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/sgodb</jta-data-source>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That "Caused by" error message is a generic message when the data source cannot be looked up.  Look earlier in the logs for a CWWJPxxxxxE error message (where the xxxxx are numbers) to see if there are more details as to why the data source could not be looked up.  Most likely either the `jdbc/sgodb` resource-ref is not defined or is not properly bound to the `jdbc/sgodb` data-source.

Comment: Please, add code where you are using persistence context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

These full JNDI names doesn't seem to work in Websphere. I used a plain "jdbc/sgodb" instead and it could find the context.

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sgodb</jta-data-source>
```

instead of

```
<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/sgodb</jta-data-source>
```